# DLLs VB.Net en un directorio concreto del equipo

Tags: vb.net

Los programas corporativos (VB6) de mi empresa utilizan unas .dll compartidas que están alojadas en una ruta c:\DLLS y registradas con regsvr32. El repositorio con las últimas versiones se encuentra en un servidor.

Ésto permite que cualquier mejora o revisión de estas .dll (generadas con VB6 y Binary Compatibility) pueda "distribuirse" de forma automática ya que periódicamente los equipos comprueban los archivos locales con los del repositorio y con "bajar" el archivo basta. Nótese que no es necesario volver a registrarla con regsrv32).

Quiero replicar ese comportamiento con VB.Net x64 y no lo consigo.

He probado registrarlo en la GAC pero eso no me sirve puesto que una vez registrada la DLL ya no es necesaria la del directorio, pues Windows la cachea. Por tanto los procesos de sobreescritura no me sirven ya que requerirían volver a registrarlas con gacutil.

He creado dos dlls compatibles e intercambiables. Que copio en el directorio "repositorio local" indistintamente.

En el prototipo de exe, la referencio con ruta y funciona correctamente SI Y SÓLO SI la defino como Copia Local = True, con lo que replica la librería de C:\DLLS a su directorio bin.

En este caso, intercambiar las dll del directorio bin es transparente para la aplicación compilada que usa una u otra versión.

Si, al referenciar la DLL cambio la propiedad Copia Local = False, aunque a nivel de desarrollo aparenta bien referenciada y no hay problemas al compilar me genera una IOException porque no encuentra el archivo.

He probado a agregar la ruta "C:/DLLS" a "Rutas de acceso de referencia..." pero tampoco resuelvo el problema.

Desestimo tener n copias de la misma DLL en cada uno de los directorios de mis n aplicaciones.

No hay algún tipo de manifiesto que indique al ejecutable buscar las DLLs en un directorio externo al de la aplicación?

Comment: Ese sistema podía tener sentido con vb6, pero con .net no tiene mucha lógica. Te recomiendo en lugar de implementar un sistema tan complejo que utilices Click Once para distribuir tu aplicación. De esta manera, cada vez que modifiques algo en ella, no tienes mas que publicarla en el servidor y todas las aplicaciones instaladas al arrancar buscaran esa nueva versión y la instalaran sin problemas.

Comment: Valoro tu aportación @Pikoh y la estudiaré. Pero significa eso que lo que yo propongo no es posible? Decirle a un exe que su dll está en una ruta concreta? Lo único que pido es que no sea su ruta de app, sino una local compartida con todas.

Comment: En principio si podrías decirle la ruta de la dll,o mejor aun que estuviera en el GAC, el problema es que cuando compilas tu aplicacion lo haces contra una version concreta de una dll, de tal manera que si modificas la versión de dicha dll la aplicación no será capaz de encontrarla, por eso te decía que no tiene mucho sentido. Para hacerlo asi yo creo que tendrias que meterte a cargar las dll por reflection, lo cual es mas complejo y yo no te recomendaría. Click Once es muy sencillo y funciona perfectamente, por eso te lo recomendaba.

Comment: Lo de la GAC se ideo para evitar el DLL hell que tenias en vb6. lo que decis perdio sentido en .net.

Comment: Entiendo el GAC, el DLL Hell y todas las ventajas "globales" del sistema. Pero sigo sin entender cómo no es posible que MIS aplicaciones, compartan MIS dlls. La única diferencia es que en lugar de estar en el directorio de la aplicación, está en otra ruta. Simplificar lo complejo es genial, pero sin que vaya en detrimento de complicar lo sencillo, no? Referenciar una dll en una ruta estática "hard-coded" local no es, ni mucho menos, complejo.

Comment: Tus aplicaciones pueden compartir tus dlls, pero es lo mismo. En el momento en el que cambies una dll, vas a tener que recompilar la aplicación y volver a distribuirla a todos los usuarios. Si sigues empeñado en hacerlo a tu manera, la unica opción que se me ocurre es cargar las dll's de forma dinámica utilizando Reflection, de esa manera es posible que puedas implementar lo que quieres, pero sigo sin recomendartelo. Click once es muy comodo de utilizar, todo lo demás es complicarse la vida en mi opinion.

Comment: Me estoy perdiendo. Tanto ha cambiado .NET en relación a VB6? DLL = Dynamic Link Library, así que por definición se enlazan dinámicamente, no? Y precisamente generar una DLL con compatibilidad binaria con su anterior (y manteniendo o aumentando su interface) precisamente lo que hace es evitar recompilar aplicaciones. O así es como yo lo aprendí cuando trabajaba con VB6.

Comment: Propongo un escenario de una aplicación que quiero instalar en varios clientes (con una particularidad distinta). Desarrollo una DLL en plan LEE_PARAMETRO, ESCRIBE_PARAMETRO que apunta a donde quiera que cada IT me diga. Para cada cliente desarrollo una DLL compatible (idéntico interface) y mi aplicación es totalmente desconocedora si los parametros se guardan en un .INI, en BBDD o en archivo local.